# Newton's third law and movement of 2 objects in contact

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Let's say that (from left to right) we have two cubes A and B in contact on a plane.

If a force F is applied (from left to right) to A the fact that A moves towards B applies a force S to B that has a reaction $R_s$ on A.

So the equations of the total forces are:
for $A: m_a \times a_a = F - R_s$;    for $B: m_b \times a_b = S$

In this situation I can't get why A and B would have the same acceleration $a_a = a_b$ that keeps them in contact. Actually why B couldn't gain an higher acceleration than A?

PS: sorry for the bad english, I'm not a native speaker, if something isn't clear I'll try to explain myself again.

Comment: If B loses contact with A then B can no longer accelerate and so A catches it up with B

Comment: And what happens if B has a lower acceleration? There's not an analytic clause that imposes $a_a=a_b$?

Comment: Then how can B move faster than A? You are correct that there can be a collision between the objects and then B does lose contact with A. Often with such a situation the assumption is made that A and B stick together.

Comment: So if I come across a situation where a force is applied to two bodies in contact the fact that they will have the same acceleration is a clause that I impose first and that I can't deduce from the equations?

Comment: A diagram would be of great help here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to explain the force applied on this object?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/245264/)

Answer (score 0):

First, agree that $S = R_S$. Now you have two equations with three unknowns

$$ \begin{aligned} m_A a_A & = F -S \\ m_B a_B & = S \end{aligned}$$

In order to solve this, you need one more equation, which comes from the possible contact between *A* and *B*. There are two cases

$$ \mbox{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases} a_A = a_B & \mbox{in contact} \\
S =0 & \mbox{not in contact} \end{cases} $$

When in contact you have $a = a_A = a_B$ and 
$$ \begin{aligned} 
 a & = \frac{F}{m_A+m_B} \\
 S & = \frac{m_B}{m_A+m_B} F
\end{aligned}$$

and when not in contact

$$ \begin{aligned} 
 a_A & = \frac{F}{m_A} \\
 a_B & = 0
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: The force of interaction between the blocks would cease to exist if the blocks went out of contact, so it's impossible for them to separate (for if they didn't they would just be pushed back together again). This is just a property of normal forces. Thus, since the positions of each block differ by a constant $x_a = x_b + \Delta x$, taking the second time derivative of each side implies the accelerations are equal $a_a = a_b$.

Comment: @TrevorKafka - You are forgetting force $F$.

Comment: I am? Can you clarify?

Comment: The accelerations are zero (constant speed) unless an external force is applied. The _op_ mentions an external force $F$.

Comment: Right, which is exactly the force that would put them back in contact again if they were to separate. My argument is that it doesn't make sense for the blocks to separate.